# Centering an infowindow and infowindow margins - Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I'm running into a little problem with my infowindows: when a marker
is close enough to the edge of the map that the map needs to pan to
display the full infowindow, it does so but not enough to allow for a
few pixels of space between the infowindow and the border of the map.
Technically this works because content is made visible but it looks
awful.

Any ideas on how to make the infowindow have a margin?

```
marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(this.latitude,this.longitude));
map.addOverlay(marker);
marker.openInfoWindow(this.infoWindow());
```

[image]

But this shows correctly if I use

```
map.openInfoWindow(marker.getLatLng(),this.infoWindow());
```

**Now how can I make the infowindow anchor starts from top of the Marker not from bottom?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens automatically in google maps so it looks like a CSS problem to me. Are you sure that there is nothing placed over the left side of the map?